# query for maximum value in row returns "0" in GoRM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Using GoRM with a mySQL database, i'm having trouble returning data from a fairly simple query.

```
var newPrsPk struct {
        presentation_pk int `gorm:"column:presentation_pk"`
    }
    db.Raw("select max(presentation_pk) as presentation_pk from presentation").Scan(&newPrsPk)

    log.Println(newPrsPk)
    log.Println(newPrsPk.presentation_pk)
```

which results in the following output:

```
[2023-06-16 09:53:27]  [43.29ms]   select max(presentation_pk) as presentation_pk from presentation  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 
2023/06/16 09:53:27 {0}
2023/06/16 09:53:27 0
```

But 0 is definitely not the max value for that column, and running the query in mySQL workbench returns the appropriate value, so I have to assume there's something wrong with how i'm writing this.

GoRM's documentation isn't amazing, but this is a pretty straightforward query, so i'm flummoxed.

"presentation_pk" is an auto-incrementing int field in my table, and this query immediately follows a GoRM Create() function (since there doesn't seem to be a way to return an auto-incremented field from mySQL). given that there's no kind of explicit "commit" function that I can see, I'm assuming GoRM automatically commits changes, and that this isn't a concurrency issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Gorm your struct variables need to be PascalCase not snake case. Take a look at the conventions [document here](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html) and then you can see about [Declaring Models here](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html).

If you change your struct to be something like this:

```
var result struct {
    PresentationPK int `gorm:"column:presentation_pk"`
}
```

Then your query should work, and then you can print out your results using `PresentationPK`

Comment: oh my christ. I don't know that I would have ever figured that out on my own. Thank you.

Comment: You're so very welcome. Gorm has been a... challenge, but it's amazing